# How to set initial fragment when reclicked on first tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

Here, i am using tab widget and having 3 tabs tab1, tab2 and tab3.I am setting fragments on each tab,like Fragment1 will set initially on first tab.I move on to different fragment from Fragment1 on a button click and then when i clicked on first tab not able to set Fragment1 as initailly was set.

Here is my code to set fragment initially on tabs:

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

```
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.base_layout);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

      mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("tab1", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list)),
            ListOfArticlesFragment.class, null);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("tab2", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.picture)),
                PicturesFragment.class, null);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("tab2", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.calendar)),
                ListOfArticlesFragment.class, null);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("tab4", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.help)),
                ListOfArticlesFragment.class, null);




}
```

When i move from ListOfArticlesFragment to another fragment on a button click, how to set 
ListOfArticlesFragment again when clicked on tab1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34961/m-t-e-t-n-o